# COMAddIn.Object is always Null

Tags: outlook, vsto

I am trying to implement a email functionality using VSTO Outlook AddIn. But 
I am getting ComAddIn.Object as always null due to this i am not able to 
access the member of VSTO AddIns

```
  Outlook.Application OutlookObj = new Outlook.Application();
        object AddinName = "OutlookAddIn";
        COMAddIn AddIn = OutlookObj.COMAddIns.Item(ref AddinName);
        IOutLookApp utils = (IOutLookApp)AddIn.Object;
        utils.CallOlMethod();
```

This is TheAddIn.cs

```
namespace OutlookAddIn
{
public interface IOutLookApp
{
    void CallOlMethod();
}  

public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    protected override object RequestComAddInAutomationService()
    {
        OutlookApp ol = new OutlookApp();
        return ol;
    }
    #region VSTO generated code
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Note: Outlook no longer raises this event. If you have code that 
        //    must run when Outlook shuts down, see 
    https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506785
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }
#endregion
public void CreateOutlookItem()
{
    Outlook.MailItem newEmail = new Outlook.MailItem
    {
        To = "example@gmail.com",
        Subject = "testing",
        Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow
    };
    newEmail.Send();
}
}
public class OutlookApp:
   StandardOleMarshalObject,
    IOutLookApp
{
    public void CallOlMethod()
    {
        Globals.ThisAddIn.CreateOutlookItem();
    }
}
}
```

What I am doing wrong here? though my AddIn class is exposed still the ComAddIn.Object is null, why? Kindly help resolving the issue.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a new instance of Outlook? Since VSTO runs in-process it would be customary that you work with the application instance in which your add-in is running. I don't normally work with Outlook, but the standard "get started" instructions certainly don't mention needing to start a new instance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/outlook-solutions

Answer (score 0):

To expose your VSTO add-in to external callers do following steps:

1. Define interface as dual and make it COM visible

   `[ComVisible(true)]
   [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
   public interface IOutLookApp
   {
       void CallOlMethod();
   }`
2. Also define a class that implements the interface as shown bellow

   `[ComVisible(true)]
   [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
   public class OutlookApp : StandardOleMarshalObject, IOutLookApp
   {
       public void CallOlMethod()
       {
           //do something
       }
   }`

Read more: [Call code in VSTO Add-ins from other Office solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/calling-code-in-vsto-add-ins-from-other-office-solutions) and 
[VSTO Add-ins, COMAddIns and RequestComAddInAutomationService](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2007/01/15/vsto-add-ins-comaddins-and-requestcomaddinautomationservice/)

Edit: 
It is also required to check **"Register For Com interop"** in project settings and make sure to run Visual Studio as administrator.

Comment: -after adding the attributes getting the below error. **Message=Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'OutlookAddIn.IOutLookApp'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{392A0EEE-0732-33E3-B3F3-721E29EE4BC8}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))

Comment: Please make sure that in your add-in project properties, in Build tab, the setting "Register for COM Interop" is checked